# Spring Boot External Tomcat File Upload

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat8

Spring Boot file upload application was deployed on an external tomcat. And set below property in the `application.properties` even though it's using tomcat `tomcat-home/temp/spring-multipart` dir to upload

```
spring.servlet.multipart.location=C:\\temp
```

Is the above property not meant for external tomcat? If it's not the solution how to create a temp folder and clean it periodically.

When uploading a file it always uses `tomcat-home/temp/spring-multipart` dir and temp files are not removed.

Spring Boot: 2.4

Comment: There is an inconsistency in your question: the error message appears to come from a UNIX system, while your configuration specifies a Windows path. Which system are you using?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Sorry I tried multiple ways `/temp`, `/uc01/temp`

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I've edited the question. actually, in Linux, I'm getting exceptions so later trying to researching how to set temp folder manually and clean it in windows.

Answer (score 1):

```
spring.servlet.multipart.location=C:\\temp
```

will have any effect only if you use embedded tomcat.

You have to change temporary directory location using `-Djava.io.tempdir` when starting tomcat https://serverfault.com/a/13698/378967

Comment: Is it possible to set for a specific application? How to clean the temp folder?

Comment: well, you just clean it. There is no magic in here. As for dir/application - I dont know

Comment: If you are concerned about the temporary uploaded files, there is no clean up to do at all: Tomcat deletes those files as soon as the request is done.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz, but in windows temp files are not deleted once uploaded

Comment: I checked on both *nix and Windows (on a recent Tomcat 9.0): the file created by Tomcat (named like `upload_7ea881f7_b695_4b33_a2e3_56c8b174e0d0_00000001.tmp`) is saved in the directory you provided and deleted after the request has been served. What version of Tomcat are you using? Or are you talking about files created by your code?

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I'm talking about temporary files only. files are not deleted from `tomcat-home 8.5\temp\spring-multipart`

Comment: Tq both sharing knowledge